# Console Application (Sockets, Threads, etc) to QT GUI

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, user-interface

I've been working in a Server application with sockets and multiple threads that handle multiple clients, and all of that stuff(Here is my [code](http://pastebin.ca/3165210)).It works just as I need, but now is just a console application and I need a very basic GUI, in which I can start the communication with clients and change some configurations of the server(Simple things). 
Is my first time with c++ GUI development, so someone recommended me to use QT Creator.
I create a simple GUI with the buttons I need, but now I don't know how to match all my Server code with the GUI. QT create 2 source files, server.cpp(as I named) in which I can access to the elements of the GUI and tell them what to do. And the other file is the main, that apparently just create a "server" instance and show it. 
So my questions are:

Where I should put all my server code?
How I should match my server code with the GUI?

I watched a lot of tutorials and visited a lot of forums but no one gave me the answers that Im looking for. Maybe I'm to noob so please help me!

Comment: Usually Server and Client are separate applications implemented as separate projects. They can be subprojects of one solution. Pretty good example with Qt Designer forms related to the sockets communication can be found here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-network-chat-example.html

Comment: thanks! I will take a look of it!